# creating namedtuple instances with kwargs

Tags: python, initialization, keyword-argument, namedtuple

I've defined a namedtuple like this:

```
My_tuple = collections.namedtuple('My_tuple', 'var1, var2')
```

I am familiar with the standard methods of making an object of the `My_tuple` class, e.g.:

```
tup1 = My_tuple('val1', 'val2')
tup2 = My_tuple(var2='val2', var1='val1')
tup3 = My_tuple._make(('val1', 'val2'))
```

(By the way - is there any difference between them?)

The problem is my input is not necessarily ordered, and instead it contains two ordered lists, e.g.:

```
vars = ['var2', 'var1']
vals = ['val2', 'val1']
```

I know I can use `setattr` or `dict`, but surely there is a more compact and Pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works, and couldn't be any more compact:

```
>>> tup4 = My_tuple(**dict(zip(vars, vals)))
>>> tup4
My_tuple(var1='val1', var2='val2')
```

To answer your side question – *"is there any difference between them?"* – no, they're all the same:

```
>>> tup1 == tup2 == tup3 == tup4
True
```